# Не отоброжается картинка Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Не отоброжается картинка, которая была загружена пользователем с POST формы, сделанной в Django Forms

[image: Вот как выглядит картинка]

Все картинки при создании обьявления сохраняются в папку media

Comment: Если в начале ссылки отсутствует слэш, то ссылка строится относительно текущего каталога - и скорее всего получается несуществующий путь

Comment: спасибо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

Надо было в начале ссылки поставить `/`
Таким образом, будет следующий код: `<img src = "/{{image}}">`